# Cannot overwrite search model once compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use the following code to search a MongoDB database using Node.js and MongooseJS.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/searches');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/search', function(req, res){
    var keyword = req.query.q;
    var searchModel = mongoose.model('search', {
        title: String,
        keywords: String,
        desc: String,
        link: String
    }, 'search');
    searchModel.find(function(err, doc){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(doc);
    });
});

app.listen(9000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:9000');
});
```

When I run this first time no error and returns all records as it should be. But the when I refresh the page I get an error saying:

> Cannot overwrite `search` model once compiled

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model must not be defined in the `app.get` callback, but on the root level of the file. For example immediately after `mongoose.connect`.

The model is stored in `mongoose` after it is complied with `mongoose.model`.
What happens when the `app.get` callback is called for the second time is that the already existing model is tried to be compiled again, which doesn't work. Hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks I realized that a while ago!